# Terminal with Vim hotkeys

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

I've enabled Vim hotkeys in my terminal on OSX, and it works fine; next step - I have some custom settings for my Vim editor (.vimrc). Is there any way to customise this vim-terminal-hotkeys too?

Comment: I do not know about osx but in Linux this was helpfull http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)

Comment: Thanks, but I know, how to remap keys in Vim. I'm rather searching of ways to 'import' this keys to terminal.

For example - I remapped esc to 'kk' for faster changes between modes. Now, I want to use this in terminal too. How can I manage to do this?

Comment: It sounds more like the function of the OS instead of vim. Do you mean changing the keyboard hotkeys of OSX?

Comment: Not exactly. 

"set editing-mode vi"

in my .inputrc enabling hotkeys from vim, but I want to add to this hotkeys my settings from .vimrc

Comment: You can't. readline's Vim mode is completely separated from Vim itself. If you want to use Vim to edit your command-line, use `<C-x><C-e>`.

Comment: Yes, intuitively I understand that, but I thought, that the settings for that mode exist and stored somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
$if mode=vi
  set keymap vi-command
  "gg": beginning-of-history
  "G": end-of-history
  set keymap vi-insert
  "kk": vi-movement-mode
$endif
```

And for zsh just do

```
bindkey -M viins 'kk' vi-cmd-mode
```

[A related question on super user on readline](https://superuser.com/questions/286781/readline-difference-between-vi-vi-move-vi-command-vi-insert-keymaps)